# Automatic Reloading of Sinatra App mounted inside Rails App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, sinatra

I've run into what I hope is an easy-ish fix for someone more experienced than me when adding a Sinatra app to an existing Rails app.

I currently have a large rails monolith that I am planning to break apart into an SPA backed by a JSON API. Since I will still need to support the monolith until the API is completed I would like to mount the API (written in Sinatra) inside the existing Rails app as I port functionality over with a goal of removing the Rails app itself in a few months. The reason I've mounted the Sinatra app inside Rails instead of setting it up as a separate service was that I wanted easy code sharing between the two as I intend to continue using ActiveRecord as my ORM in Sinatra once the migration is complete.

I've mounted the Sinatra mockup inside the Rails app without any issues using the Rails routes.rb file as:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  mount API::Core, at: '/api'
...
end
```

I'm not doing any work with config.ru as mounting the API inside the routes.rb file seemed to suit my needs. If I need to put in some more legwork to get this running properly that is not an issue.

The entrypoint for the sinatra app is also fairly simple with just a couple controllers loaded in to segment the routing:

```
require 'sinatra/base'
require 'sinatra/json'

require_relative 'controllers/first_controller'
require_relative 'controllers/second_controller'

module API
  class Core < Sinatra::Base
    register Sinatra::FirstControllerApi
    register Sinatra::SecondControllerApi

  end
end
```

The problem I'm running into is one I expected with Sinatra but haven't been able to flex my google-fu enough to find a solution. Rails automatically reloads code on each change/request as expected but Sinatra does not. Every time I change controller code in the Sinatra API I need to restart the entire Rails server to serve the new content. Since my dev environment runs in docker containers this can take a while to start up each time and is becoming cumbersome.

Is there a 'canonical' solution to the problem of automagically reloading the Sinatra app mounted inside the Rails app or am I just over-complicating the problem? I know there are some gems for Sinatra that apply to this space but I haven't seen any info in how to get them working in this 'odd' edge case.

Please let me know if you need any more info, hopefully I've provided enough for someone to comprehend my issues.

Answer (score 0):

Just like with a Sinatra app on it's own, a Sinatra app mounted inside o rails will not automatically reload as you make changes. Typically in Sinatra people would use external tools to help solve this problem, so they might set up something like [Shotgun](https://github.com/rtomayko/shotgun) to watch the directory and restart the server any time a change has happened.

But, like most things in Rails, there is a way hook into it's functionatly for your own programming benefit.

#### ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker

Rails has a handy `ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker` that can watch a file, or a list of files. When they change it will call back to a block. You can use this to reload the Sinatra app -- or anything else for that matter.

In your case you might want to add the following to `config/environments/development.rb` in the config block for the application:

```
Rails.application.configure do
  # ...

  sinatra_reloader = ActiveSupport::FileUpdateChecker.new(Dir["path/to/sinatra/app/**"]) do
    Rails.application.reload_routes!
  end

  config.to_prepare do
    sinatra_reloader.execute_if_updated
  end
end
```

---

Robert Mosolgo has a good write up on his blog: [Watching Files During Rails Development](http://rmosolgo.github.io/blog/2017/04/12/watching-files-during-rails-development/). His approach is a little more thorough, but more complicated.

Comment: I tried this and got `undefined local variable or method `sinatra_reloader'`